# How to have multiple "sub strings" when using the in operator with a string

Tags: python-3.x, operators

I have a hopefully simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to.

In the following code, I am creating an input validation feature to make sure the user inputs any of four valid "operations" (A.K.A the single letters 'a', 's', 'm', or 'd' and nothing else), so, I'm checking if the "operation" the user inputs is NOT equal to the any of the strings 'a', 's', 'm', or 'd'. If the condition is met, an error message will be printed and the program will be restarted as the code (mostly) shows.

```
print("Select an operation:")
print("Add  (a)"), print("Sub  (s)")
print("Mul  (m)"), print("Div  (d)")

operation = input()
if "a" not in operation: 
    print("Invalid operation.")
    continue
```

Please tell me a way I can check if the operation matches ANY of the four letters. And, just to clear up, I don't mean that I need to OR (the logic function) 'a', 's', 'm', and 'd'.

All correspondence and help is much appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: First note: use raw_input() rather than input() for Python 2.x; remember that, prior to Python 3, input() was really akin to eval(raw_input()) --- dangerous.  Next you can test membership by simply making a set() of your allowed operations: if operation not in set(('a','s','m','d')): ... (or even just use the tuple: if operation not in ('a','s','m','d'): ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`not in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) operator with a tuple of values to test for:

```
if operation not in ('a', 's', 'm', 'd'):
```

The condition of the above if-statement will evaluate to `True` if `operation` does not equal any of the values in the tuple `('a', 's', 'm', 'd')`.

---

Note too that you are using `continue` incorrectly: it may only be used inside a loop.

If you want to loop until the user enters a proper value, you can use something like this:

```
while True:                                # Loop continuously
    operation = input("Enter a value: ")   # Get the input
    if operation in ('a', 's', 'm', 'd'):  # See if it can be found in the tuple
        break                              # If so, break the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

ummm perhaps

```
operation = input()
assert operation in  ('a', 's', 'm', 'd'), "Error you must use one of  'a', 's', 'm', or 'd'"
```

I guess

basically you want to check that *your operation* **in**  *list of options*

of coarse if your list of options is huge, then using a set is much more appropriate ... or a dictionary that provides a mapping from operations to methods ie

```
operations = { 
    "a":add,
    "s":sub,
    "m":mul,
    "d":div
} #these are methods defined elsewhere
operation = input()
if operation in operations:
   operations[operation]() #call the method
```

Comment: An assert failure will raise an exception ... if he wants the program to continue he should use a loop:  while True: ... if operation not in ('a','s','d','m'): ... else: break

Comment: yeah ... but i figured I'd let him work that one out on his own

Comment: ... along with every other novice who comes upon this answer in perpetuity?  Not the best plan for welcoming future Python programmers to the field.

Comment: meh Im not sure someone who is just looking for a copy paste answer is someone who I want to be a future programmer in any language ... I would like them to at least grasp why they do something someway ... in addition I pretty clearly spell out what he needs to do below the code ... but it doesnt really matter there's always plenty of copy and paste answers to pretty much any question ... often even from me ... I think helping them understand the concept is much more helpful to future programmers than a copy/paste solution\

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
allowed_operations = set(('a', 's', 'm', 'd'))
while True:
    operation = input() # raw_input() for Python earlier than 3
    if operation not in allowed_operations:
        print ('Error: Must choose one of a, s, m, d\nPlease try again')
    else:
        break
```